# Make Grid Tabel using Alive PDF

Tags: jquery, report, alivepdf

How to make grid table using alive pdf?

Answer (score 1):

```
var pdf:PDF = new PDF(Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.LETTER);

var grid:Grid = new Grid(array, 100 , 100, new RGBColor(0xFFFFFF),
                                           new RGBColor (0x000000), false,
                                           new RGBColor( 0x000000 ));           
pdf.addGrid(grid);
```